# RecyclerView - How to select items by dpad/keyboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can you select items of a RecyclerView using the dpad and/or keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Make your items focusable. It will let you navigate it via dpad. Then you'll need to add your logic to "select" focused item on press. (whatever your select key is)